# Why do I get "PrehashSignature is not implemented for Signature" error when using k256 library?

Tags: rust, ecdsa, secp256k1

I simply tried to create a recoverable signature using the k256 crate [documentation](https://docs.rs/k256/latest/k256/ecdsa/recoverable/index.html) as a reference as follows, but for some reason I get a compile error regarding the `sign` method to create the signature.

```
use k256::ecdsa::{recoverable, signature::Signer, SigningKey};
use rand_core::OsRng;

fn main() {
    let signing_key = SigningKey::random(&mut OsRng);
    let verifying_key = signing_key.verifying_key();
    let message = b"ECDSA proves knowledge of a secret number in the context of a single message";

    let signature: recoverable::Signature = signing_key.sign(message);
}
```

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `k256::ecdsa::recoverable::Signature: PrehashSignature` is not satisfied
 --> src/main.rs:9:57
  |
9 |     let signature: recoverable::Signature = signing_key.sign(message);
  |                                                         ^^^^ the trait `PrehashSignature` is not implemented for `k256::ecdsa::recoverable::Signature`
  |
  = help: the following other types implement trait `PrehashSignature`:
            ecdsa::Signature<C>
            ecdsa::der::Signature<C>
            k256::schnorr::Signature
  = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `Signer<k256::ecdsa::recoverable::Signature>` for `k256::ecdsa::SigningKey`
```

I have enabled the "ecdsa" features as follows:

```toml
k256 = { version = "0.11.3", features = ["ecdsa"] }
```

Is there any other setting I need to do?

Comment: As the example you're re-implementing states: "NOTE: make sure to enable **both the ecdsa and keccak256** features of this crate for the example to work."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @isaactfa mentioned at the comment, I need to enable BOTH "ecdsa" and "keccak256" features:

```toml
k256 = { version = "0.11.3", features = ["ecdsa", "keccak256"] }
```